# Microsoft Teams User presence application not working

Tags: skype-for-business, microsoft-teams, ucwa

I've recently created a c# application using UCWA sdk that updates the MS Teams user's presence instantly and log it.

The application worked fine and got exact presence when I change my presence in both skype for business client and MSTeams client (I used the same account for testing in MS Teams and SFB).

But from last week, the presence gets updated only when I change the presence in Skype for business client. When I change my presence in MSTeams client i am not getting the actual presence instead it shows offline.

Is there any problem with the co-existence mode for the account that I've used for testing?

Answer (score 0):

If any of the users are using Teams instead of SfB for online meetings, UCWA won't reflect their presence.

Comment: Bliss Is there any way to make to use Sfb as a default app for online meetings?.
One more thing..How can i get MSTeams user's presence without Sfb's involvement?.